# Delete from table in all databases containing table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to create a T-SQL query which are deleting all rows in the table `Logins` in ALL databases containing this exact table, so it can be run without any errors.

I want to reuse the code to other stuff as well, e.g. finding all active users from all databases containing the table `Users`. Therefore, I think, the best solution would be a pure `T-SQL` solution. This way the query can even become an automated job run by `SQL Server Agent`

Is it possible? And how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build some dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = ''
select @sql = @sql + 
  'use [' + name + '] ' + 
   'if exists (select * from sys.tables where name = ''Logins'') ' + 
   'delete from Logins '
from sys.databases where name not in ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')

print @sql
--exec (@sql)
```

Uncomment the `exec` line to actually run the code rather than just see what would be executed.